# '"Eclipse" would like to access files in your Document folder' alerts continuously while running multiple Eclipse instances

Tags: eclipse, macos, security, permissions, macos-catalina

[image]

The OS continuously asking for the above permission while I'm running multiple Eclipse instances.

I have already given the permission and I tried by disabling and enabling the permission several times.

I'm using,

- macOS Catalina (version: 10.15.3 (19D76))
- Eclipse IDE for Java    Developers (Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0), Build
  id: 20190314-1200)

Anything that I can do to stop this please.

Comment: Exact the same here

Comment: Did you try using 4.13? 4.11 is not notarized for use with Mac OS 10.15. Only eclipse versions 4.13(2019-09) onwards are notarized

Comment: @Sravan Before try with 4.13, I reinstalled eclipse in Documents folder and now I'm not seeing the issue. I will try for a few days with the 2 eclipse instances (I'm using 2 eclipse instances for the server and the client.) that I have installed in the Documents folder and will add this as the answer if I'm not having the issue again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone having this issue, try installing eclipse in the Documents folder. That what I tried and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto system preferences > Security & privacy > Full Disk Access > add Eclipse
2. Restart eclipse & PC

then your java able to get listFiles()

[image]